# Split string without losing delimiter (and its count)

Tags: python, string, split

I'm trying to split a string like below on spaces:

```py
string = "This            is a                      test."

# desired output
# ['This', '            ', 'is', ' ', 'a', '                      ', 'test.']

# actual output, which does make sense
result = string.split()
# ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test.']
```

There's also [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) which keeps the delimiter, but not in the way I hoped:

```py
import re
string = "This            is a                      test."

result = re.split(r"( )", string)
# ['This',
# ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ',
# 'is', ' ',
# 'a', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', ' ',
# 'test.']
```

I can do something like this and achieve the result I want:

```py
string = "This            is a                      test."
result = []

spaces = ''
word = ''
for letter in string:
    if letter == ' ':
        spaces += ' ' 
        if word:
            result.append(word)
            word = ''
    else:
        word += letter
        if spaces:
            result.append(spaces)
            spaces = ''
if spaces:
    result.append(spaces)
if word:
    result.append(word)

print(result)
# ['This', '            ', 'is', ' ', 'a', '                      ', 'test.']
```

But this doesn't feel like the best way to do it. Is there a more Pythonic way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `re.split` with the expression of `(\s+)`:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "This            is a                      test."
>>> re.split(r'(\s+)', string)
['This', '            ', 'is', ' ', 'a', '                      ', 'test.']
>>>
```

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/IDSGIL/1).

Comment: Make it a `r'(\s+)'` to avoid a DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence `\s`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
import re
def main_function(string):
    return re.split(r'(\s+)', string)

print(main_function("This            is a                      test."))
```

Output:

```
['This', '            ', 'is', ' ', 'a', '                      ', 'test.']
```

[Example on Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/86sjBz/1)

Answer (score 2):

You could also avoid doing a string split and instead use `re.findall`:

```py
string = "This            is a                      test."
matches = re.findall(r'\s+|\S+', string)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['This', '            ', 'is', ' ', 'a', '                      ', 'test.']
```

The regex alternation `\s+|\S+` alternatively matches groups of whitespace or non whitespace characters.